# Not able to use dos2unix on UNIX machine

Tags: linux, unix, dos2unix

I try to use dos2unix command on unix machine but it gives me error like --

```
 data_load]$ dos2unix a.csv a.csv
-bash: dos2unix: command not found
```

Then i use ---

```
data_load]$ yum search dos2unix
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

=================================================== N/S Matched: dos2unix ===================================================
dos2unix.x86_64 : Text file format converter
```

Is there any way that i can use it and i can not log in as ROOT

Comment: Try unix.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not a helpdesk.

Comment: Simplifying horribly: `yum search` tells you what is available in the app store, not what you have actually installed.

Answer (score 2):

You could ask your sysadmin to install `dos2unix`. Apparently he didn't install it yet.

You might compile it from its [source code](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/). If it has a `configure` script (from [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf)) you might pass a `--prefix=$HOME/soft` argument to that script and later add `$HOME/soft/bin/` to your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

Perhaps using [tr(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) might be enough...

Comment: Do you know why it says not found but when i do yum search dos2unix then it says matches ? What is the reason and solution and if i could do it on my own because i have to make changes in the production ENV in my deliverable...

Comment: *not found* (given by your shell) means that your sysadmin did not install `dos2unix` (or that you messed up your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) to the point of removing `/usr/bin` from it).

Comment: Then in production env they also need to install it as i am not aware if they have it or not ?